# c++ std::thread problems in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to execute this code.

```
BOOL genFunctionOne(std::vector <char> functionOneBuffer, int functionOneCharCount)
{
  int lineCountTest = 0;
  int characterCountTest = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < functionOneCharCount; i++)
  {
    if (functionOneBuffer[i] == '\n')
      lineCountTest++;

    characterCountTest++;
  }

  return FALSE;     
}
```

With this call.

```
std::thread funcThreadOne( [&] { functionOne = genFunctionOne( functionBufferOne, functionCharCountOne ); } );
```

And everytime I call the function.  I get..

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Debug Error!

Program:... my.exe

R6010
-abort() has been called

Please retry to debug the application.
```

The Break Point is cause by... crt0msg.c

```
            if (rterrnum != _RT_CRNL && rterrnum != _RT_BANNER && rterrnum != _RT_CRT_NOTINIT)
        {
            switch (_CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_ERROR, NULL, 0, NULL, L"%s", error_text))
            {
            case 1: _CrtDbgBreak(); msgshown = 1; break;
            case 0: msgshown = 1; break;
```

Thanks in advance.

I have actually tried to run other thread calls in the same program and have had no luck.  It could be my compiler, are there any libraries that need to be linked in build options with #include ?

Comment: Why is there a size parameter if `std::vector` is in use? It has a `size()` function.

Comment: does it happen also in release mode?

Comment: @cf16 Haven't tried it in release mode, been shying away from it, but I could try it and get back to ya.

Comment: @chris Thanks for pointing that out, is using size() in the function faster than passing the variable?

Comment: @LightKeep It's O(1) IIRC

Comment: No idea what that means Rapptz.

Comment: Does it happen if you don't use a lambda?  Does it happen if you call that lambda from the current thread?

Comment: This happens when you *call* the function? or is it when you call the function, then exit scope? I ask because you're clearly passing open references into your lambda from *somewhere*. Are *they* going out of scope as well?

Comment: I added join() to the corrent >.< thread call and it appears to be working now, except that join stops the executing while loop from running which is exactly why I'm using threads in the first place, to avoid this.

Comment: testing with detach now

Comment: Lol, Ok, so using Detach is working how I wanted.  Except, now I have another Debug Error.  vector is not incremental. BAH!

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  I was losing hair with the stress.  Now I can work on this next error...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you join or detach the thread before exiting scope? Because you have to. Exiting scope with a thread running calls terminate.

Comment: I preform absolutely no other tasks on the function after it's called.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @LightKeep Well there you have the problem. You have to join or detach the thread.

Comment: Hmm, I'll give that a try.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: Just FYI, I have seen numorous examples where there was no join or detach.  So I figured it was only necessary when you wanted to wait for the code to finish executing before continuing with the main function.  Which to me, almost sounds counterintuitive to why threads exist at all.

Comment: @LightKeep: You have to either join or detach the thread. Otherwise, the implementation has no idea whether it's safe to clean up after the thread (when it terminates) or not.

Comment: Release gets the error:      Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in SplitterScripter.exe.      _debugger_hook_dummy = 0;

Comment: @David Well, that could very well be the case and I'm going to try that next, but just to let you know, this error pops as soon as the execution of the for loop starts, not as it's ending.  If that makes any difference.

Comment: added funcThreadOne.join(); directly after the std::thread call... Same error.

Comment: Is there anything about this code, other than the fact that it actually doesn't do anything, that could be preventing it from working?  I actually think the fact that it doesn't do anything is further proof that it should work.. lol.  No global variables referenced.

Comment: @LightKeep Boost thread used to (maybe still does) call detach automatically in destructor, std::thread doesnt do that, it calls terminate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that lambdas usually are used only inside the complete-expression where they appear, and that the temporary lambda object will be destroyed at the end of that complete-expression.

I would expect `std::thread` to make a copy of the functor object passed in, to avoid lifetime problems.

But you can ensure there's no issue via:

```
auto threadProc =  [&] { functionOne = genFunctionOne( functionBufferOne, functionCharCountOne ); };
std::thread funcThreadOne(threadProc);
funcThreadOne.join(); // <- make sure you do this before threadProc goes out of scope
```

(Note: the Standard does require `std::thread` to make a copy of the functor and all arguments, and also requires a lambda object to have a copy-constructor. But Visual C++ may not meet these requirements yet.)

Comment: If I use detach will the thread return BOOL still be passed to functionOne?

Comment: @LightKeep: As long as you make sure `functionOne` is still alive and hasn't gone out of scope, yes.  If it is out of scope, bad things happen.